# How to zoom out in maps in an ios app using storyboard?

Tags: ios, mkmapview, zooming

I am creating an iOS app using storyboard to plot some locations in a map. While running it, in the simulator, whatever button(mouse button) I click, the view just zooms in. How can I zoom out. Whether I should place a scroll bar in the view, or is there any other possibilities.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Holding Alt on the keyboard will allow you to make a pinch gesture.